# Pjax and Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, pjax

Currently integrating jquery pjax, will do my best to explain. I have it working inside the first view however when accessing the URL address directly from address bar I get the view without the `@extends('layout.main')`.

Here is my setup:

Routes, one route is for the `retailers.index` view and the other is for my GET parameter and `retailers.stores` view.

```
Route::get('retailers', array(
    'as' => 'retailers', 
    'uses' => 'SiteController@retailers'));

Route::get('retailers/{city}', array(
    'as' => 'find-retailers',
    'uses' => 'SiteController@getRetailers'));
```

Controllers:

```
public function retailers() {

$listings = DB::table('retailers_listings')
->orderBy('counter', 'desc')
->groupBy('country')
->get();

return View::make('retailers.index')
->with('retailers_listings', $listings)
}

public function getRetailers($city) {    

$locations = DB::table('retailers_listings')
->orderBy('country', 'asc')
->Where('city', $city)
->get();

return View::make('retailers.stores')
->with('retailers_listings', $locations);
}
```

href with pjax and URL route to `retailers.stores` view - *using find-retailers*

```
<a data-pjax href="{{ URL::route('find-retailers', array('city' => $string)) }}">
{{ $string }}
</a>
```

Inline JS

```
$(document).pjax('[data-pjax] a, a[data-pjax]', '#pjax-container')
```

If I am loading /retailers (index) everything works and if I press the link it will load `store.retailers` view inside the `<div id="pjax-container"></div>` and the URL will change to retailers/{country}. If I load from the URL address bar directly it will only load the view without `@extends('layout.main')`, as I do not call that in my `retailers.stores` view because I load retailers.stores in pjax.

Basically it works, but not when loading directly for address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has no idea you're using something like PJAX.

You should include `@extends('layout.main')` in each route. In order to work with PJAX, you should make `layout.main` only spit out the site layout if `Request::ajax()` is false.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Could you give me an example?

Comment: Just wrap all the layout bits you don't want included in the PJAX calls in `@if(!Request::ajax())` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT use `@if(!Request::ajax())` to determine if the request is by PJAX.

PJAX will provide specific custom headers (`HTTP_X_PJAX` and `HTTP_X_PJAX_CONTAINER`) that you should be using to determine what the request is asking for.

```
@if($request->server->get('HTTP_X_PJAX'))
```

---

For a simpler solution...

You should take a look at this laravel package for working with PJAX:

https://github.com/simonstamm/laravel-pjax

It uses the headers mentioned above properly and will even automatically send back the appropriate part of a view for a request.

Comment: The problem with that package is it does dom crawling to find the content. There's a far better approach - look at the headers, if it's a pjax request, don't include the layout. You can do that by extending the laravel controller and modifying the behaviour.

Both PJAX implementations for laravel are horrible.